# How to make pointstick buttons behave like touchpad buttons

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, dell-latitude

I'm running Windows 10 on a Dell Latitude 5480 computer that has separate pointstick (above the touchpad) and touchpad (below the touchpad) buttons. Whenever I click one of the pointstick buttons there is around half a second when the touchpad is not responsive, so I have a delay every time I try to click and drag something, or try to click and scroll immediately after the click. There is no such delay when using the touchpad buttons with either the touchpad or the pointstick, or the pointstick buttons with the pointstick.

Is there a way to make the bahaviour the same for both sets of buttons, so I can use them without the touchpad locking up? I tried looking for relevant options in the Dell Pointing Devices application, as well as Windows touchpad options but none of them seemed to fix the issue. My drivers are also up to date.

I don't care if a solution breaks functionality of the pointstick since I never use it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can try disabling the touch pointer in the Device Manager. Or if your installation is still stock, the Dell Touchpad application should have options for the Touch Pointer. If you can't find anything....then just unplug it physically. https://i.imgur.com/sLAKeyK.png

Comment: I'm already able to disable the touch pointer / pointer buttons but that's not what I want to achieve. I like using the buttons above the touchpad. I'm asking for a way to change their behaviour so they don't lock the touchpad for half a second every time I press them.